# Alternando Páginas Web A Cada Tanto Tempo

Tags: javascript, asp

Bom dia!

Possuímos na empresa dois paineis em duas páginas ASP distintas. Precisamos que no painel 1 e no painel 2 haja alguma forma de um chamar o outro a cada tanto tempo. Haveria alguma forma talvez com JAVASCRIPT?

Exemplo:

Painel 1 fica 3 minutos exibindo na TV do setor e depois dos 3 minutos passará para o painel 2. Este ficará por exemplo, 30 segundos e voltará para o primeiro. Há alguma forma de fazer este procedimento?

Comment: O que queres dizer por "painel"? queres algo tipo slides que vão mudando com o tempo duas imagens ou elementos do HTML?

Comment: Na verdade são duas páginas ASP que buscam dados de um banco, apresentamos elas apenas em divs, paragrafos e nada mais. Tudo com bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No painel 1 voce acrescenta isso no header:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh"content="180; url=http://ENDERECODOPAINEL2.COM">
```

No Painel 2 voce acrescenta isso no header:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh"content="30; url=http://ENDERECODOPAINEL1.COM">
```

Comment: Perfeito! Era exatamente isso que precisava! obrigado!